# How to map database structure in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hello is it possible to map hibernate structure like that?

Let say I have n tables like tableTrait1, tableTrait2, tableTrait3 ... tableTraitN, each other has some different number of columns, but every table has id.

and there is table Document

I want to connect these table with Document.

So my idea is to create table like TraitToDocumentTable

which would be like

id | idOfDocument| idOfTraitTable | nameOfTraitTableToJoin

but how to map into hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as below.

```
Public Class TraitToDocumentTable{

Private int id;

@@OneToOne
Private TableTrait1 tableTrait1;

@@OneToOne
Private TableTrait2 tableTrait2;

@@OneToOne
Private TableTraitN tableTraitN;

}
```

Comment: I meant I have a lot of table with traits :P not TableTraitN, but Trait3, Trait4, Trait5.. Trait100

Comment: Yes if you gonna maintain any relationship then above is the way

Comment: But your expectation like - id | idOfDocument| idOfTraitTable | nameOfTraitTableToJoin...

Comment: You can create table but can not mapping you have to manually I think.